# No se me muestra el resultado en el input

Tags: javascript, html

**mi problema es que no se cambia el valor en el input, pero si se está haciendo correctamente en console.log**, y la verdad es que no entiendo por qué y no encuentro ninguna solución, a ver si ustedes entienden el por qué no se cambia el valor dinámicamente cada vez que cambio de mes. La página la cargo mediante AJAX en el index. Adjunto imagen para que vean el problema. Ante todo, muchas gracias por su tiempo.

**El código JS para el problema es el de var var tiempo = document.getElementById("meses");**

Código html

```
<body onload="presupuesto()">


    <div class="contenedor">
       
        <section class="main-2">

          
          <form action="" autocomplete="on" id="formulario-principal">
            <fieldset class="presupuesto-fieldset">
                <legend> Datos</legend>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Tu nombre" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,}" id="nombre" required> <br><br>
                <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
                <input type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Tus apellidos" pattern="[A-Za-z]{6,}" id="apellidos" required> <br> <br>
                <label for="telefono">Teléfono de contactos:</label>
                <input type="tel" name="telefono" placeholder="Tu teléfono" pattern="[0-9]{9}" id="telefono" required> <br> <br>
                <label for="mail">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Tu email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required> <br> <br>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="datos-pagina">
                <legend>Web</legend>
                <label for="tipoWeb">Tipo de pagina web: </label>
                <select name="tipoWeb" id="tipoWeb" required>
                    <option value="" selected></option>
                    <option value="basica">Basica</option>
                    <option value="intermedia">Intermedia</option>
                    <option value="avanzada">Avanzada</option>
                </select> <br> <br>
                <label for="meses">Plazo en meses: </label> 
                <input type="number" name="meses" placeholder="Meses en los que quieres que esté lista tu web" min="1" max="12" pattern="[0-9]{1,2}" id="meses" value="0" required><br> <br>
                <label for="caracteristicas"> Marque las opciones desesadas: </label> <br> <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="quienesSomos" id="cb">
                <label for="quienesSomos">Quienes somos</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="dondeEstamos" id="cb">
                <label for="dondeEstamos">Donde estamos</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="galeriaFotos" id="cb">
                <label for="galeriaFotos">Galería de fotos</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="eCommerce" id="cb">
                <label for="eCommerce">eCommerce</label> <br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="gestionInterna" id="cb">
                <label for="gestionInterna">Gestión Interna</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="noticias" id="cb">
                <label for="noticias">Noticias</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="facebook" id="cb">
                <label for="facebook">Facebook</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="twitter" id="cb">
                <label for="twitter">Twitter</label>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Presupuesto estimado (en euros)</legend>
                <input type="number" id="resultado" name="resultado" value="0"> <br> <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar">
                <input type="reset" value="Limpiar" name="reset">
            </fieldset>
          </form>
      </section>
      
        
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/TF.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Código JS

```
function presupuesto(){

selectPagina= document.getElementById("tipoWeb");
resultadoPresupuesto = 0;
cuenta = document.getElementById("resultado");
    
selectPagina.addEventListener("change", () =>{
    elemento = document.getElementById("tipoWeb").value;
    

    if( elemento == "basica"){
        /*Desmarcar checkbox para que no desvirtúe la cuenta final*/
        var checkboxs = document.forms[0];
        var i = 0;
        for(i; i < checkboxs.length; i++){
            checkboxs[i].checked=false;
        }
        /* Ponemos de coste de la página básica a 300*/
        resultadoPresupuesto = 300;
        cuenta.value = parseFloat(resultadoPresupuesto);

        } else if
            (elemento == "intermedia"){
            /*Desmarcar checkbox para que no desvirtúe la cuenta final*/
                var checkboxs = document.forms[0];
                var i = 0;
                for(i; i < checkboxs.length; i++){
                checkboxs[i].checked=false;
            }           
            /* Ponemos de coste de la página intermedia a 600*/
                resultadoPresupuesto =600;
                cuenta.value = parseFloat(resultadoPresupuesto);
            }
                else if (elemento == "avanzada"){
                    /*Desmarcar checkbox para que no desvirtúe la cuenta final*/
                    var checkboxs = document.forms[0];
                    var i = 0;
                    for(i; i < checkboxs.length; i++){
                    checkboxs[i].checked=false;
                }
                    /* Ponemos de coste de la página avanzada a 900*/
                    resultadoPresupuesto =900;
                    cuenta.value = parseFloat(resultadoPresupuesto);

                    } else{ null } 

                    console.log(cuenta.value);
});
var tiempo = document.getElementById("meses");
    tiempo.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        var mPercents = {
            1: "0.05",
            2: "0.1",
            3: "0.15",
            4: "0.2"
          };
          /* Precio base o 0 para evitar NaN */
          var basePrice = parseFloat(cuenta.value) || 0;
          /* Valor a descontar o 0 si no está en el objeto */
          var mDiscount = parseFloat(mPercents[e.target.value]) || 0;
          console.log(resultadoPresupuesto);
          /* Calculamos precio final */
          document.forms[0].resultado.value = resultadoPresupuesto - (resultadoPresupuesto * mDiscount);
          /* Test */
          console.log(document.getElementById("resultado").value);
    });   
            

var checkboxs = document.forms[0];
checkboxs.addEventListener("change", (elemento) =>{
    var contador = 0;
    var resultadochecked = 0
for (var j = 0; j< checkboxs.length; j++){
    if (checkboxs[j].checked == true){
            contador ++;
        }
    }

resultadochecked = (contador * 400);

cuenta.value = resultadoPresupuesto + resultadochecked;
}); 
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bueno revisando lo que tienes encuentro que efectivamente logra realizar el cambio pero en tu js tienes lo siguiente:*

```js
var checkboxs = document.forms[0];
checkboxs.addEventListener("change", (elemento) => {
  var contador = 0;
  var resultadochecked = 0
  for (var j = 0; j < checkboxs.length; j++) {
    if (checkboxs[j].checked == true) {
      contador++;
    }
  }

  resultadochecked = (contador * 400);

  cuenta.value = resultadoPresupuesto + resultadochecked;
  console.log('ejecuta ', resultadoPresupuesto, resultadochecked, resultadoPresupuesto + resultadochecked);
});
```

*Este fragmento se ejecuta cada que encuentre cambios en tu formulario. ciertamente, cuando seleccionas el tipo de página y luego procedes a ingresar el plazo. después de cambiar el resultado se ejecuta ese fragmento de código cambiando tu valor al valor del tipo de página seleccionada.*

*En ese fragmento al final tienes lo siguiente:*

**cuenta.value = resultadoPresupuesto + resultadochecked;**

*Allí cambias el valor del campo resultado.*

*No alcanzas a notar el cambio en el DOM debido a que es muy rápido. por eso ves que en el console.log se refleja el cambio del valor pero en el campo del resultado no ves ese mismo.*

*Si quieres observar lo que te digo, agregale a ese fragmento de código al final un console.log y verás el orden en que te los imprime.*

*Espero te sirva.*

Comment: Te quiero, la de horas que me ha llevado y era eso...